# Azure Databricks - Write to parquet file using spark.sql with union and subqueries

Tags: apache-spark-sql, parquet, azure-databricks

Issue:

I'm trying to write to parquet file using spark.sql, however I encounter issues when having unions or subqueries. I know there's some syntax I can't seem to figure out.

Ex.

```py
%python
    
df = spark.sql("SELECT
          sha2(Code, 256) as COUNTRY_SK,
          Code as COUNTRY_CODE,
          Name as COUNTRY_NAME,
          current_date() as EXTRACT_DATE
       
        FROM raw.EXTR_COUNTRY)
       
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
          -1 as COUNTRY_SK,
          'Unknown' as COUNTRY_CODE,
          'Unknown' as COUNTRY_NAME,
          current_date() as EXTRACT_DATE")
          
df.write.parquet("dbfs:/mnt/devstorage/landing/companyx/country", 
   mode="overwrite")
```

WHEN doing a simple query I have no issues at all, such as:

```py
%python
    
df = spark.sql("select * from raw.EXTR_COUNTRY")
df.write.parquet("dbfs:/mnt/devstorage/landing/companyx/country/", 
   mode="overwrite")
```

Comment: why do you need second part of the union? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is an example, I will have the need of queries that are in use of unions or subqueries etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotes solved the issue, the sql-script itself wasn't the issue. So using  tripple quotes (""" or ''') solved the issue.

```
 %python
        
    df = spark.sql("""SELECT
              sha2(Code, 256) as COUNTRY_SK,
              Code as COUNTRY_CODE,
              Name as COUNTRY_NAME,
              current_date() as EXTRACT_DATE
           
            FROM raw.EXTR_COUNTRY)
           
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT
              -1 as COUNTRY_SK,
              'Unknown' as COUNTRY_CODE,
              'Unknown' as COUNTRY_NAME,
              current_date() as EXTRACT_DATE""")
              
    df.write.parquet("dbfs:/mnt/devstorage/landing/companyx/country", 
       mode="overwrite")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your code that needs to be fixed:

- you're using single quotes (`"`) for multi-line string.  Instead you need to use tripple quotes (`"""` or `'''`)
- your SQL syntax is incorrect for second part of the query (after `union all`) - you didn't specify `FROM` which table you need to pull that data.  See [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select.html) for details of the SQL syntax.

I really recommend to debug each subquery separately, maybe first using the `%sql`, and only after it works, put it into the `spark.sql` string.

Also, because you're overwriting the data, it could be easier to use `create or replace table` syntax to perform everything in SQL ([docs](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using.html)), something like this:

```sql
create or replace table delta.`/mnt/devstorage/landing/companyx/country/` AS (
SELECT
          sha2(Code, 256) as COUNTRY_SK,
          Code as COUNTRY_CODE,
          Name as COUNTRY_NAME,
          current_date() as EXTRACT_DATE
       
        FROM raw.EXTR_COUNTRY)
       
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
          -1 as COUNTRY_SK,
          'Unknown' as COUNTRY_CODE,
          'Unknown' as COUNTRY_NAME,
          current_date() as EXTRACT_DATE
          FROM ....
)
```